# Android / отправка смс SmsManager

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sms

Как разрешить приложению отправлять смс сообщения? Ошибка доступа.

Добавил в Manifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

---

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnSend.setOnClickListener({
            val numberText = R.string.phoneNumber
            val messageText = "Hello, member!"
            SmsManager.getDefault()
                    .sendTextMessage(numberText.toString(), null, messageText.toString(), null, null)

        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пермишн `android.permission.SEND_SMS` относится к `dangerous permissions`, поэтому для его получения, кроме записи в манифесте, нужно запросить разрешение у пользователя в рантайме. Подробности можно найти в официальной документации:
 [requesting permissions at run time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).